# How to add css class to cloud tag anchors?

Tags: functions, widgets

How to add a CSS Class to `ul` and anchor element of Tag Cloud generated through `wp_tag_cloud` function?

I want the default class for `ul` of `wp-tag-cloud` to be `tag-cloud` and anchor tag would have `btn btn-xs btn-primary` class.

```
<ul class="tag-cloud">
   <li><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="#">Apple</a></li>
   <li><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="#">Barcelona</a></li>
   <li><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="#">Ipod</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also modify the anchor CSS class with the [`wp_generate_tag_cloud_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_tag_cloud_data/) filter (4.3+).

With that filter we can modify the following anchor data:

- `id`
- `url`
- `role`
- `name`
- `title` (removed in 4.8)
- `slug`
- `real_count`
- `class`
- `font_size`
- `formatted_count` (added in 4.8)
- `aria_label`      (added in 4.8)
- `show_count`      (added in 4.8)

The style attribute is hardcoded, as can be seen from the 4.8 version:

```
$a[] = sprintf(
    '<a href="%1$s"%2$s class="%3$s" style="font-size: %4$s;"%5$s>%6$s%7$s</a>',
      esc_url( $tag_data['url'] ),
      $tag_data['role'],
      esc_attr( $class ),
      esc_attr( str_replace( ',', '.', $tag_data['font_size'] ) . $args['unit'] ),
      $tag_data['aria_label'],
      esc_html( $tag_data['name'] ),
      $tag_data['show_count']
  );
```

Note that we can change the font-size **unit** with:

```
wp_tag_cloud( [ 'unit' => 'rem', 'smallest' => 1, 'largest' => 4 ] );
```

or e.g. with the [`widget_tag_cloud_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_tag_cloud_args/) filter for the tag cloud widgets.

**Example:**

Here we append the `btn btn-xs btn-primary` classes to anchors in all tag clouds:

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', function( $tag_data )
{
    return array_map ( 
        function ( $item )
        {
            $item['class'] .= ' btn btn-xs btn-primary';
            return $item;
        }, 
        (array) $tag_data 
    );

} );
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it support all the tags? I tried the `style` and it didn't work.

Comment: The style attribute is not supported, but it's used to set the font_size

Comment: Yea :c It seems like the `preg_replace` is the only way to get rid of the font size in the tag widget.

Comment: yes that seems to be the case, ... or remove it trough DomDocument or  we could reconstruct them from the tags array, without the style part, within the `wp_generate_tag_cloud` filter, more work though ;-)

Comment: The sad part is that `font_size` will only accept numbers and append a `pt` to it. So i can't even use `unset` as a value...

Comment: yes the style part is unflexible, maybe you could file a trac ticket to make it more flexible? ;-)

Comment: Oh I'm sure they will consider your proposal more seriously, but if you don't have the time, i will do for sure.

Comment: you should go for it ;-) but make sure there's no other open ticket for this and explain why this should be changed, e.g. with use cases and code change examples.

Comment: Alright i did. Also linked this question and insisted that @birgire requested a trac ticket for it ( JK ).

Comment: hehe best of luck with it ;-)

Comment: But note you can modify the unit from pt to e.g. em

Comment: Why didn't you tell me this before i mention this in the ticket that you can't :D Is it possible to unset the font-size?

Comment: You can modify the font-size unit but the `style="font-size..."`  part is hardcoded. I thought you meant a ticket to make that more flexible, e.g. to be able to remove the font-size part completely with the  wp_generate_tag_cloud_data  ;-)

Comment: [This](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40924) is the ticket i created for the very purpose you mentioned. I don't see an edit button, but i would appreciate any note you can give me to add/edit the ticket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59907/discussion-between-birgire-and-jack-johansson).

Answer (score 3):

The tags are wrapped in a `DIV` element in the latest WordPress version the day i'm writing this answer (4.7.5), and their class is `tagcloud`, so i will move to the next thing that is asked in the question.

The tags can be modified using the `wp_generate_tag_cloud` filter. By writing a `preg_replace` you can change the class to whatever you wish. Here is an example:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_tag_cloud', 'my_tag_cloud',10,1);
function my_tag_cloud($string){
   return preg_replace('/class="tag-link-.+ tag-link-position-.+"/', 'class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"', $string);
}
```

Anchors have the `tag-link-X tag-link-position-Y` class which X and Y are numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The classes are hardcoded in `wp_generate_tag_cloud()` function. Your only option there is to modify final string output via `wp_generate_tag_cloud` filter.